# I have an issue with PES 2020 for Android

Tags: android, pro-evolution-soccer-2020

I just downloaded the game and finished the tutorials and played my first match (I think this first match is the last part of the tutorial).

Then, a white message appeared taking most of screen space. I'm not sure if it's supposed to be an ad, or if I received a reward, or it's an information message. But it's totally white blank.

I clicked on the (X) button to hide it. It goes then appears again.

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Well,  the message looks exactly like when you open a notification message but it's blank.

The solution is to clear the data, and cash to do a fresh start and select the the language and the team...etc again. I selected a different team this time ;)

It might be useful to skip the tutorial to avoid any notifications or pop up messages.

This should solve the problem but when you open the notification, you will find them blank too but at least you will be able to close the blank notification and continue gaming normally and it won't open again automatically.